# Winsock recv() endlessly receives 10053 WSAECONNABORTED error

Tags: c++, mfc, winsock

I hope I am not missing a simple solution to this, but I have been looking for days.

I have a client/server Winsock MFC architecture for my MMO which has been working fine for the most part.

On rare occasions when a client closes a connection the server will receive the 10053 `WSAECONNABORTED` error message.  Even from a legitimate closing of the client.  Here is the server code that handles in the incoming messages, apologies for un-optimized code:

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
LRESULT CDXDisplay::DefWindowProc(UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{

switch (message) //handle the messages
{
case 39245: //Network port number
    {
        switch (lParam) //If so, which one is it?
        {
        case FD_ACCEPT:
    VGlobal::sSocket.AcceptSocket();

            break;

        case FD_CONNECT:

            break;

        case FD_READ:
            VGlobal::sSocket.receiveSocket = wParam;
            VGlobal::sSocket.ReceivePacket();

            break;

        case FD_WRITE:

            break;

        case FD_CLOSE:

            VGlobal::sSocket.CloseClientConnection( wParam );
            break;
        }
    }
    break;

    default:
        if(message == WM_EXITSIZEMOVE || (message == WM_SIZE && (wParam == SIZE_MAXIMIZED /*|| wParam == SIZE_RESTORED*/)))
        {
            OnSizeScreen();     
            MainVant->SetDisplayMode(0);
        }

        return CDialog::DefWindowProc(message, wParam, lParam);
        //return CWnd::DefWindowProc(message, wParam, lParam);
}



return CDialog::DefWindowProc(message, wParam, lParam);

}
```

The program will receive the packet, trigger FD_READ, and call `ReceivePacket()`

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
int SocketServer::ReceivePacket( char * tBuffer, int tReceived )
{

ClientInfo::_packetInfo tPacket;

if( tBuffer == NULL )
{

    char buffer[4096];
    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
    int received = recv( receiveSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1, 0 );

            //received = -1 and the WSAGetLastError() ID is 10053
    if( received == -1 )
    {
        int tError = WSAGetLastError();

        return 0;
    }

    if( received == 0 )
        return 0;

            //Handle packet data

    _recvData tRData;
    tRData.length = received;
    //tRData.recvBuffer = buffer;
    tRData.recvSocket = receiveSocket;

    CString convStr;
    LPTSTR aStr = tRData.recvBuffer.GetBufferSetLength(received);
    memcpy( (void*)aStr, buffer, received );

    recvDataList.push_back( tRData );


}


return 1;
}
```

All I am simply doing to ignoring the packet, and waiting for the next window message.  However, when I do that, `DefWindowProc()` continuously receives the `10053` error over and over endlessly.

I would have assumed reading the `recv()` function example on MSDN and other examples I find on the web that all I needed to do is "ignore" the message and move on, however this does not seem to be the case.  Then I just assume my client ping timeout code will process any remaining data for the client pre-error, then remove the client information when done.

I am terribly sorry if there is a simple solution I need to have to handle this error, but I just cannot seem to find it.

**Update 1:**

While doing further testing, it seems that before I receive the non-stop socket messages going into `DefWindowProc()` then into the `recv()` function where I get non-stop `10053 WSAECONNABORTED` results from `recv()` result, my server's `send()` function also triggers the `10053 WSAECONNABORTED` first.  These are obviously related in some way but I am still confused as in how.

So what is most likely happening is that when the client shuts down, it doesn't have time to send its disconnect messages to the server in time, so the server is still storing packet data in the `send()` command for the client's socket and filling it up until it finally it hits the `10053` error on the `send()` function.

I am not sure what is going on behind the scenes after this point.  But Once the `send()` functions hits the `WSAECONNABORTED` error, then the `recv()` gets endless window messages also returning `WSAECONNABORTED`.

Now I am making complete guesses here... but I must be assuming that the `send()` function still has a full buffer of data waiting to send to the already closed client, and the network is just continually sending the data to a non existent client, then sends the error back in the `recv()` function?  So am I supposed to somehow remove the data in the `send()` buffer so that it is cleared out, then the server can continue on as normal?

Comment: What's with the `39245`? Does your keyboard not come equipped with letters?

Comment: Sorry, 39245 is simply the port number that is being used, when a packet is received that is the port in which it came from.

Comment: I would presume that you need to close the socket when you receive `WSAECONNABORTED`.

Comment: Are you referring to closing my server socket that calls the `send()`? If so, what happens to all the other clients that are connected to the server?  If I close the server socket then open it up again, does that reset everyone's connection to the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I believe I understand now.  In my mind I was assuming that creating a socket was like memory allocation, and if you allocated memory on the client, you had to deal with it on the client, but a network socket connection can be dealt with as a 2 way street.  I was not understanding that if I created a socket connection on the client, that I could close it on the server using `closesocket()`.  I thought I had to deal with it either on the client again, or let the socket work itself out until it realized that the connection was gone, and it would terminate its own actions.

So the answer was all I hopefully needed to do was call `closesocket()` on the client's socket on the server side.

So your answers were right about calling `closesocket()`, I just was not wrapping it around my head that I could close the client's socket on the server side, since its "technically" not on the client or the server at all and can be death with in both programs.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Microsoft Support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925513): On a computer that is running Microsoft Windows Server 2003, you run a network program that uses a Winsock connection. When the program calls the recv Winsock function, you receive this error code

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925513

Comment: I understand the reason I am getting the error, I am just trying to make the server not infinitely loop through my `DefWindowProc()` infinitely with the 10053 error.  Also this error is occurring on many different Window OSes, mostly when the client and server are just running on Windows 7.  I am trying to understand why `DefWindowProc()` continuously processes the same Winsock error message over and over again.